# How to in-line modify a variable in a shell script?

Tags: bash

I have a shell script that sets a variable `RESULT=` as empty to begin with. Then, the script makes a curl get request if `RESULT` is empty (`if [ -z $RESULT ];then...`), and then prints it out, telling the user to set the empty variable.

I am wondering if there is a way for me to in-line modify the `RESULT` variable only if it is empty, so that afterwards, the variable instead reads a string, such as

```
RESULT="SUCCESS"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? what do you mean _afterwards, the variable instead reads a string, such as_ . Unless you set the variable it will be always be empty

Comment: Sorry, I mean changing the actual text of the file itself to be from `RESULT=` to `RESULT="SUCCESS"`

Comment: You don't have to explicitly set it to the empty string. `if [ -z "$RESULT" ]` (the quotes are important) has the same result whether `RESULT` is unset or is set but null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
: ${RESULT:=$(curl ...)
```

If `RESULT` is initially empty or unset, `curl` will run and its output assigned to `RESULT`. Otherwise, `curl` is not run, and `RESULT` retains whatever value it started with. (Note that `RESULT` may be an environment variable, with a value before the script actually starts.)

You can extend this to handle arguments as well.

```
# :-, not :=
RESULT=${1:-$(curl ...)}
```

`curl` only runs if the first argument is the empty string or not present:

```
yourScript
yourScript ""
```

Otherwise, it assigns whatever the first argument is to `RESULT`:

```
yourScript "$(curl ...)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Supply an assigning default.

```
if [[ b0Gus == "${RESULT:=b0Gus}" ]]; then... # RESULT now b0Gus if it was empty
```

This returns the value of RESULT if it has one, else it sets it and returns that. Note that it is more like `((++x))` than `((x++))` in that it applies the change *before* returning the content to the test operator.

If you use a dash instead of equals, it returns the alternate value, but doesn't set the variable -

```
if [[ b0Gus == "${RESULT:-b0Gus}" ]]; then... # RESULT still empty after match
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html for more.

You can apply this by passing it as args to a no-op, too.

```
: ${RESULT:=b0Gus}
```

The `:` just returns true, but the parser still evaluates its arguments, which will set the var if empty - this is similar to a Perl `||=` assignment, though that isn't inline.

Comment: Also note, you can replace `b0Gus` with a command substitution like `$(curl ...)`, and `curl` will only be executed if the default value is needed.

Comment: And/or you can use another variable as the new value.

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned running `curl` if the value is empty, so I though it worth emphasizing.